# How do I launch Windows Anaconda python from WSL Ubuntu?

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Anaconda for Windows 10.  I later installed Ubuntu under the WSL.  I would like to run the python from Anaconda in the Ubuntu shell.  Is this possible?  How do I activate the environment?

Alternatively, if I install Anaconda under ubuntu, will I be able to use that environment in Visual Studio 2019?  (My end goal is to do my python dev in VS2019, be able to run in debug mode there, and also use the bash shell to run python scripts.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use VS on Ubuntu's Anaconda python. However, you will need to install it there as well, and for now there's no official support for WSL GUI from Microsoft, though you can still install third party programs that will do that for you.

In order to use Anaconda under the WSL shell you will first need to install it there.

You can do that by going into the Anaconda webpage and copying the link to download the latest Linux version, and under the bash you type `wget [link]`.

After the download is done you can install it running `sudo bash [name of the archive]`

You can find its name by typing `ls`, and it should match the version that you just downloaded.

After that you should reload the bash `source ~/.bashrc` and you should now be able to use Anaconda under the Linux bash, though it's not possible yet to have it on the GUI.

There are multiple alternatives if you still want it displaying in your browser, you could either change the path to output in your Windows browser, install a complete Linux GUI or just use a Windows software to display the anaconda GUI alone.

Assuming you want the later:

Go to MobaXterm website and download it. This is a lightweight software that comes with various inbuilt tools to access SSH server, VNC, SFTP, Command Terminal, and more.

- Open the MobaXterm, once you have that on your system.
- Click on the Session option given in the Menu of its.
- Select WSL available at the end of the tools menu.
- From Basic WSL Setting, click on the Dropdown box and select Ubuntu and press the OK button.
- Now you will see your Ubuntu WSL app on MobaXterm, great.
- There, simply type: `anaconda-navigator`
- That’s it, this will open the graphical user interface of the Anaconda running on Ubuntu WSL app of Windows 10.
- Start creating environments and Installation of different packages directly from the GUI of Navigator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `anaconda` on the linux partition.

Yes, you can use `VS2019` on `Ubuntu`

[download](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) - [install](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)

Comment: Can you add some detail on how to setup VS2019 to use the Ubuntu's anaconda python?

Comment: No, sorry: 1- I do not use VS; 2- There are many tuts online that I used to verify it was feasible; 3- this is not in the scope of your original question, if you need to, ask a new question.

Comment: I will add a different question, however, to improve the quality of your answer, you should include links to the sources you mentioned.  Simply a literal answer of "Yes" is helpful (I am going this path), but including the How-To links is more helpful.  Thank you for your answer, btw.  If you don't have time to fill in the links, I'll do so myself once I find some good ones.